# How should I address the readers in a product review?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, nouns, formality, repetition

Occasionally, I leave reviews on the games I play. I mostly use "the player" or "players" in my text to have a rather formal tone. However, my formal writing is not as rigid as you may suspect as I keep it simple and avoid the use of unnecessary fancy words. I can't help but feel it's getting heavy with too many "players...players...".

Would it be OK to address the reader with personal nouns (you), or even a mix of "players" and "you" to keep it diverse?

Comment: when giving reviews and other formal reports, it is sometimes possible to use the pronoun "we", as in me (the one giving the review), you (the one reading the review) and all other players. for example: "after completing the level, we are rewarded with..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a consistent writing tone that is speaking to the player, then use the word "you".

> When I talk to you, I am talking to you.

To get an example of how not using "you" in this context is strange.

> When I talk to the questioner, I talk to the questioner.

Of course you are the questioner, so it might make it very hard to understand that last sentence until you realize you are the questioner.

Writing and speech should keep the audience in mind.  If you are presenting information, present it to the expected audience.  That means "The player moves into the next room." might be perfect if you are presenting to a group of managers, game investors, developers, or so on; but, this would be non-idiomatic when presenting to a group of players.